# Не запускается MySQL Server на CentOS

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, centos, mariadb

Случайно завершился процесс MySQL и служба mysqld больше не запускается.

При командах `service mysqld start` и `service mysqld restart` пишет:

`Redirecting to /bin/systemctl start mysqld.service

Job for mysqld.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mysqld.serv
ice" and "journalctl -xe" for details.`

Команда `service mysqld status`

```html
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status mysqld.service                                                                
● mysqld.service - MySQL Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mysqld.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)                       
   Active: failed (Result: start-limit) since Fri 2019-04-19 14:15:08 MSK; 6min ago
     Docs: man:mysqld(8)                                                                                           
           http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/using-systemd.html                                                   
  Process: 2374 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid $MYSQLD_OPTS (code=exi
ted, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 2352 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/mysqld_pre_systemd (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)                           
                                                                                                                   
Apr 19 14:15:08 CentOS-75-64-minimal systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Server.
Apr 19 14:15:08 CentOS-75-64-minimal systemd[1]: Unit mysqld.service entered failed state.                         
Apr 19 14:15:08 CentOS-75-64-minimal systemd[1]: mysqld.service failed.                                            
Apr 19 14:15:08 CentOS-75-64-minimal systemd[1]: mysqld.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.             
Apr 19 14:15:08 CentOS-75-64-minimal systemd[1]: start request repeated too quickly for mysqld.service             
Apr 19 14:15:08 CentOS-75-64-minimal systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Server.
Apr 19 14:15:08 CentOS-75-64-minimal systemd[1]: Unit mysqld.service entered failed state.                         
Apr 19 14:15:08 CentOS-75-64-minimal systemd[1]: mysqld.service failed.
```

Если с админки isp входить в базы данных, ошибка:

`Не удалось подключиться к базе данных '' Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)`

Не знаю что делать, все способы перепробовала.

Comment: `journalctl -xe` что выдаёт?

Answer (score 2):

Скорее всего что-то не так с сокетом: либо его кто-то занял, либо его нет.

проверим:

```
lsof /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

ну если нет lsof, то нужное его поставить `yum install lsof`

в ответ получим либо что-то вроде:

```
COMMAND  PID  USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF  NODE NAME
mysqld  3930 mysql    4u  unix 0xffff8800ba42cc00      0t0 42918 /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
mysqld  3930 mysql   27u  unix 0xffff88007f9eac00      0t0   931 /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
mysqld  3930 mysql   77u  unix 0xffff8802345dac00      0t0 42919 /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
...
```

тут видно кто занял сокет
и нужно завершить это приложение `kill -9 *pid*`

либо:

```
lsof: status error on /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock: No such file or directory
```

...

значит его нет
можно его создать (если не от рута, то соответственно всё это через `sudo`):

```
mkfifo /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
chown -R mysql /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

ну и запустим:

```
service mysqld start
```

либо, если ЦентОС 7:

```
systemctl start mysqld
```